# How do i restructure xml service error am getting?

Tags: android

i keep getting this error message when i launch emulator

$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.diceactivity/com.example.diceactivity.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.diceactivity/com.example.diceactivity.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices

Comment: THat command doesn't launch an emulator, its attempting to launch an app on an already running emulator.  And the reason it fails should be in your logcat.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.